# How do I test for feature support with C++?

Tags: c++, g++, option-type, c++17

I'm trying to use `::std::optional<T>` with g++ 6.3.1 and the -std=c++17 flag. It turns out I have to actually `#include <experimental/optional>` and use `::std::experimental::optional<T>` instead. How do I test for this so I can include the right header once the feature is truly included in the standard library?

Is there instead an option I can give g++ so it includes the 'experimental' features as if they were standard?

Comment: See also the [feature testing recommendations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros)

Comment: @BarrettAdair - Please put that into an answer. Because it's **the** answer to the question that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__cpp_lib_experimental_optional` from the [feature testing recommendations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros).

Comment: I'm going to edit this comment into being a little more comprehensive. But, it is the exact answer I was looking for. And I didn't know it, or I would've answered it myself earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The story here, in a nutshell, is that gcc has a habit of being an "early adopter" for various bits that are proposed for inclusion in an upcoming revision of the C++ standard, but before those bits get formally adopted.

There is, of course, no guarantee that the implementation of those bits in gcc will end up in the final C++ standard without any subsequent tweaks. As such, they get released, as in this case, as `<experimental/optional>` rather than `<optional>`.

You can expect that this header file will be renamed to `<optional>` in a future release of `gcc`, perhaps with any final tweaks needed to make it match the final specification in the C++ standard.

It should be fine to just go ahead and write your own header files and translation units to `#include <experimental/optional>` instead of `#include <optional>`. There is no compiler switch to do this for you. When you upgrade your compiler to a newer version, that implements the final C++ standard specification, and has an actual `<optional>` header file, you can simply update your source code accordingly.

You could also place a stub file named `optional` in your source tree, containing only a:

```
#include <experimental/optional>
```

Then add a `-I .` compilation option, in order for `#include <...>` to also look in the current directory; then refer to `#include <optional>` in your source.

`-I .` will find this stub, which will pull in `experimental/optional`. When you update `gcc` later, you can simply drop this file, and the `-I .` option.

[More information](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Comment: Don't forget the new C++17 `__has_include` feature ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas - I just discovered those not 2 minutes ago and was going to request they be mentioned. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0061r1.html